# Creating A Loop To Hash The Contents of An Entire Folder

Tags: python, hashlib

I'm brand new to this website (and coding as a whole) and have been trying to find a way to successfully hash the contents of a folder and plop all the hashes into a .csv!

Below is a picture of what I have so far! Again, I know it leaves a lot of room to be desired... but it functions at the very least! The biggest problem I'm having right now is ensuring that every file in the folder, rather than just the folder itself, is being hashed and put into the .csv file.

Edit: For clarity, my hope is to be able to do the following:

1. Ask the user which folder of files they would like to hash, and verify that the folder exists (done).
2. Next verify where the user would like to have the hashes output to (done).
3. Then have the program hash all the files included in the target folder, and list all of the hash values in a CSV in the location chosen by the user.

Currently I believe the program does the first two, but instead of hashing all the files in the folder it instead hashes the folder itself. I'm not really sure how to make the program instead target all the files and write their hashes into a single csv file rather than just hashing the folder.

Thank you again for any help in advance!

[What I have So Far](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBYkE.png)

```
import os
import hashlib
import os.path


def main():
    print('Kurtis\'s SHA-256 Hashing Program')
    print(f'Note: Please make sure in insert the entire folder directory! ex: C:\Data\Hashme\Yeehaw')
    folderd = input('What is the directory of the folder that contains the files you would like to hash?: ')
    if os.path.exists(folderd):
        os.chdir(folderd)
        print(f'Thank you for selecting a folder! The folder you have chosen to hash can be found at {folderd}')
        hashlocation = input('Which folder would you like your hash output to be stored in: ')
        while os.path.exists(hashlocation):
            verification = input(f'Excellent! {hashlocation} exists. Are you sure this is where you\'d like to store your hashed files (Y/N)?')
            if verification == 'Yes' or verification == 'yes' or verification == 'y' or verification == 'Y':
                def update_kurt(folderd, kurt):
                    with open(folderd, 'rb') as f:
                        while True:
                            block = f.read(2 ** 10)  # Magic number: one-megabyte blocks.
                            if not block:
                                break
                            kurt.update(block)

                for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
                    kurt = hashlib.sha256()
                    for file in files:
                        fullpath = os.path.join(path, file)
                        update_kurt(fullpath, kurt)
                    os.chdir(hashlocation)
                    with open('SHA-256.CSV', 'w') as f:
                        f.write(kurt.hexdigest())
                        print(f'Congratulations! Your hash for the folder {folderd} was successful and can be found in {hashlocation}. You will now be taken back to the beginning so that you might be able to hash further files if you so desire.')
                        os.chdir(folderd)
                        f.close()
                        main()
            else:
                print(f'Apologies! I am either too dumb to infer meaning from your response "{verification}" or you responded in the non-affirmative. For the sake of my creator\'s grade I will take you back to the beginning to start over!')
                main()
        else:
            newdir = input(f'I\'m sorry! {hashlocation} does not currently exist. Would you like to create a new folder at that directory?(Y/N)')
            if newdir == 'Yes' or newdir == 'Y' or newdir == 'yes' or newdir == 'y':
                os.mkdir(hashlocation)
                print(f'Wonderful! Your new folder "{hashlocation}" has been created. You will now be looped back to the beginning to create your desired hash files.')
                main()
            else:
                print('Sounds good! I\'ll just loop you back to the beginning!')
                main()
    else:
        print(f'{folderd} does not exist, please try again.')
        main()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Please post your code rather than a screenshot of your code :)

Comment: for some more clarity, does this behave the way you expect, or are you receiving an error? (what is it if so?) if you want a review, try https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'll clarify here and in the post! It is currently not behaving the way I want. I'm not getting an error of any sort, but I believe that the program is hashing the folder and putting the output in a CSV at the target directory, rather than hashing every file in said folder and putting all of them in the CSV.

Comment: Seems like the issue is you're building one hash. If you move the `kurt = hashlib.sha256()` into `update_kurt` and `return kurt.hexdigest()`, you can easily then change the code to output the hash of each file.

Comment: How would you move `kurt=hashlib.256()` up? Would you completely delete that portion of the for loop and just plop it after `kurt.update(block)`? @Peilonrayz